# get value from bootstrap selectpicker text box using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-selectpicker

I want to get value from bootstrap select picker text box  if user input some text  but it didn't trigger anything

```
<select id="user_search" class="form-control" data-live-search='true' search='true'>
    <option>option 1</option>
    <option>option 2</option>
    <option>option 3</option>
</select>

<script>
    $("user_search# input").live("keyup", function (e) {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `"user_search# input"` is absolutely wrong it should be `"#user_search"` and there is no input at all.

Comment: @Zydnar  if you use data-live-search=true then textbox will come with selectpicker

Comment: @faiz you'd be correct, but only if you're running it after bootstrap is initialised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have added those js and CSS and the jquery code as I have written

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('keyup', '#userDropdown .bs-searchbox input', function(e) {
    alert($(this).val());
  });
  
  $(document).on('keyup', '#cityDropdown .bs-searchbox input', function(e) {
    alert($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="userDropdown">
  <select name="user_search" data-live-search="true" class="selectpicker">
    <option>option 1</option>
    <option>option 2</option>
    <option>option 3</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="cityDropdown">
  <select name="city_search" data-live-search="true" class="selectpicker">
    <option>City 1</option>
    <option>City 2</option>
    <option>City 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I will check it and will inform you about this code, you only understood  my requirement.

Comment: @faiz, Did that help ?  ?

Comment: @faiz I have given you the snippet, and you could see its working there,. . . Do you have multiple select picker  on a page ? anyways I got you point. let me try and get back to you asap

Comment: yes, ihave multiple selectpicker for this reason I have mentioned I want to refer specific text box  by selecting its parent id (id='user_search')

Comment: what should I do now if I have 3 selectpicker in same page

Comment: @faiz , I have updated my answer , What you can do is you can have a unique id div outside the select picker.. check it I have added the multiple select picker now. and accessing it individually .  Hope that helps.

Comment: I am surprised in your code it is perfectly working, but in my code still same issue I.e not getting any alert

Comment: Make sure jquery code is written in document.ready part like I did

Comment: thanks for your valuable support I need to think in another way your code is in correct manner to get data from text box